# How to get cron job working in heroku (production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have the following in my schedule.rb - I'm using the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"
job_type :script, "'#{path}/script/:task' :output"

every :sunday, at: "3:00 AM" do
  runner "Event.clear_expired"
end
```

And I'd like to have this running in production on Heroku.

How might I set it up?

I've looked at a couple like scheduler etc.. but they seem really un-intuitive.. any guidance would be helpful!

**Update**:

```
task :weeklydelete do
  set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"
  job_type :script, "'#{path}/script/:task' :output"

  every :sunday, at: "3:00 AM" do
  runner "Event.clear_expired"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/marketplace/scheduler) addon, which is free, and then you can set your job up in there. You can't use `whenever` on Heroku.

Comment: Awesome, I've added the Scheduler.. if you look at my code above, how might I convert that to work with the scheduler, that's where we're having some difficulity. Thanks!

Comment: Create a rake task that encapsulates what you need to happen (in this case, `Event.clear_expired`). After testing it locally using `rake mytask` to ensure it works as desired, you should be able to push the code, then do `heroku run rake mytask` to run it on the Heroku environment. After you've ensured that works as well, you can create an entry in Scheduler for `rake mytask`. See [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) for more info.

Comment: Updated post with the new rake task, pls let me know if it looks O.K to you. Thanks!